How to make a recurring timer publish changes to the main thread Swift?
I am wanting a check to be done every 5 mins. For this to happen there obviously needs to be a timer of some description running in the background.
I have a timer func which calls a working func where I will need to make a network call. The network call then updates a @Published var which is watched by a global .alert. I am able to get this @Published update to work without a recurring timer running, but I need the timer...
The message I get is:
"Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior." I get this alert pop up 6 times per attempt.
I know Timer.scheduledTimer is inherently synchronous but have tried Task.sleep as well which yields the same result.
EDIT: 11th Sept 2024. I still don’t have an answer for this. Nothing I am trying is working. I have looked at @lorem ipsum response and have tried to implement:
cancellable = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)

It seems any way I do this, I get the same result.
EDIT: I have updated the code to be even more basic and have implemented the new timer method. I have tried using:
DispatchQueue.main.async

and
Task { @MainActor in }

I have made a super basic reproducible version of this error with the timer set to 1 seconds. If you let the timer continue to run and don't cancel the timer from the alert, you will see the issue as it tries to update on the main thread. Thank You
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FirstAppApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var app = AppState()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MenuView()
                .environmentObject(app)
        }
    }
}

MenuView
struct MenuView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            TabView {
                Tab("Plan", systemImage: "house") {
                    ContentView()
                }
            }
        }
        .alert("New ATIS", isPresented: $app.newAtisAvailable) {
            Button("Stop Timer", role: .cancel) {
                Task {
                    app.atisTimer.invalidate()
                }
            }
        } message: {
            Text("There is a new ATIS for ....")
        }
    }
}

ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var app: AppState

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        Button(action: {
            Task {
                await app.startTimer()
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("Start timer")
        })
    }
}

}
AppFuncs
import Combine
@MainActor
class AppState: ObservableObject {

@Published var newAtisAvailable: Bool = false
var cancellable: Cancellable?

func startTimer() async {
    cancellable = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { currentTime in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.newAtisAvailable.toggle()
            }
        }
}

}

Don't publish atisTimer. It should just be var atisTimer: Timer? Why are you using async and Task to start and stop the timer? Toggling the newAtisAvailable property doesn't seem like the right thing to do.  Don't you just want to set it to true?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/replacing-foundation-timers-with-timer-publishers

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Publishing+changes+from+within+view+updates+is+not+allowed%2C+this+will+cause+undefined+behavior%22

I am publishing atisTimer because I do: atisTimer.invalidate() from elsewhere within the program so I need access to it globally. Also, I am just setting toggle() on it for this repro example to show it messing up.

Timer is irrelevant to rendering, so you don't have to make it @Published.

Thank you @INCHMAN1900 I have made the change in my code now. The issue wasn't that but the @Published var newAtisAvailable: Bool = false being updated was causing the problem to appear.
